# Mobile Backend Starter - iOS client (App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, ios7, xcode5

anyone got the error below when compiling the "iOS Client" from google "Mobile Backend Starter"?
Xcode 5.02, iPhone iOS 7.

```
duplicate symbol _kCloudBackendClientID in:
    /Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CloudBackendIOSClient-gjhkqbarudkpudeeytxgowaihtym/Build/Intermediates/CloudBackendIOSClient.build/Debug-iphoneos/CloudBackendIOSClient.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MessagesTableViewController.o
    /Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CloudBackendIOSClient-gjhkqbarudkpudeeytxgowaihtym/Build/Intermediates/CloudBackendIOSClient.build/Debug-iphoneos/CloudBackendIOSClient.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Constants.o
duplicate symbol _kCloudBackendClientSecret in:
    /Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CloudBackendIOSClient-gjhkqbarudkpudeeytxgowaihtym/Build/Intermediates/CloudBackendIOSClient.build/Debug-iphoneos/CloudBackendIOSClient.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MessagesTableViewController.o
    /Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CloudBackendIOSClient-gjhkqbarudkpudeeytxgowaihtym/Build/Intermediates/CloudBackendIOSClient.build/Debug-iphoneos/CloudBackendIOSClient.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Constants.o
duplicate symbol _kCloudBackendChainName in:
    /Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CloudBackendIOSClient-gjhkqbarudkpudeeytxgowaihtym/Build/Intermediates/CloudBackendIOSClient.build/Debug-iphoneos/CloudBackendIOSClient.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MessagesTableViewController.o
    /Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CloudBackendIOSClient-gjhkqbarudkpudeeytxgowaihtym/Build/Intermediates/CloudBackendIOSClient.build/Debug-iphoneos/CloudBackendIOSClient.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Constants.o
duplicate symbol _kCloudBackendServiceURL in:
    /Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CloudBackendIOSClient-gjhkqbarudkpudeeytxgowaihtym/Build/Intermediates/CloudBackendIOSClient.build/Debug-iphoneos/CloudBackendIOSClient.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MessagesTableViewController.o
    /Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CloudBackendIOSClient-gjhkqbarudkpudeeytxgowaihtym/Build/Intermediates/CloudBackendIOSClient.build/Debug-iphoneos/CloudBackendIOSClient.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Constants.o
ld: 7 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

In file MessagesTableViewController.m

Change:

```
#import "Constants.m"
```

to:

```
#import "Constants.h"
```