# Error compiling the iOS Backend Sample of GAE

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, backend

When I try to compile te App :
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-mobile-backend-starter-ios-client

As described in : https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/ios/

This return multiple errors

This is due the new version of iOS? The new version of XCode?

Comment: can you also provide details about the errors received?

Comment: Follow the suggestion mentioned in this post (if you are seeing similar errors)- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21690911/mobile-backend-starter-ios-client-app-engine

Comment: Thanks, but I just applied this "patch" this only let XCode link the code, not Run it. There are more errors that make the code unstable in runtime

Comment: it Finally: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: I can upload a image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSException is thrown when there are rogue outlets mappings. You can check this out in the connection inspector.

[image]

I have downloaded the project and receiving the same NSException error. It looks like the project is missing some of the class files like Splash1ViewController, Splash2ViewController which are referred by the viewcontrollers in iphone.storyboard. The files are available under sample folder but not added as part of the Project. Not sure the about the reason for this..

I have managed to get this running by adding the missing files to sample folder. Constants.h, SplashViewController.h & .m, Splash2ViewController.h & .m , Splash3ViewController.h & .m

[image]

Also in MessagesTableViewController.m changed Constants.m to Constants.h.

Updated project can be downloaded from here - https://github.com/rshankras/solutions-mobile-backend-starter-ios-client

Hope this gives you some pointers to play around with the sample project.

Comment: There is already an open issue - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-mobile-backend-starter-ios-client/issues/3

Comment: Thanks, I'm one of this in the issue (MPPT), I Still work around this